# Button scaling in winapi

Tags: user-interface, winapi, visual-c++

I am creating a simple calculator and I have a problem with scaling all elements. They have to scale with main window but I have no idea how to perform such a thing 
Here is part of code:

```
#define ID_BUTTON0 0
#define ID_BUTTON1 1
#define ID_BUTTON2 2
#define ID_BUTTON3 3
#define ID_BUTTON4 4
...

case WM_CREATE:
{
    CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,0, 0, 0, 0,hWnd, HMENU(ID_TEXTFIELD), 0, NULL);
    CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"CE",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,0, 0, 0, 0,hWnd, HMENU(ID_BUTTONCE), 0, NULL);
    CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"C",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,0, 0, 0, 0,hWnd, HMENU(ID_BUTTONC), 0, NULL);
    CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"/",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,0, 0, 0, 0,hWnd, HMENU(ID_BUTTONDIV), 0, NULL);
    CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"X",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,0, 0, 0, 0,hWnd, HMENU(ID_BUTTONMUL), 0, NULL);
    CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"7",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,0, 0, 0, 0,hWnd, HMENU(ID_BUTTON7), 0, NULL);
    CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"8",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,0, 0, 0, 0,hWnd, HMENU(ID_BUTTON8), 0, NULL);
    CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"9",WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,0, 0, 0, 0,hWnd, HMENU(ID_BUTTON9), 0, NULL);
    ...

    resize_window(hWnd);
}
break;
case WM_SIZE:
{
    resize_window(hWnd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return 0;
}
void resize_window(HWND hWnd) {

int buttonxsize = WINDOWSIZEW / 4;
int buttonysize = WINDOWSIZEH / 6;
int posx = WINDOWSIZEW / 4;
int posy = WINDOWSIZEH / 6;
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
SetWindowPos(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_TEXTFIELD), 0, 0, 0, WINDOWSIZEW, buttonysize, SWP_NOZORDER);
SetWindowPos(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_BUTTONC), 0, 0, posy, buttonxsize, buttonysize, SWP_NOZORDER);
SetWindowPos(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_BUTTONCE), 0, posx, posy, buttonxsize, buttonysize, SWP_NOZORDER);
SetWindowPos(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_BUTTONDIV), 0, 2 * posx, posy, buttonxsize, buttonysize, SWP_NOZORDER);
SetWindowPos(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_BUTTONMUL), 0, 3 * posx, posy, buttonxsize, buttonysize, SWP_NOZORDER);
...
}
```

and so on...

After compiling I obtain such a thing :[image]

How do I make it work?

Comment: Looks like you have most of what you need. Watch for `WM_SIZE` messages and resize your child controls using `SetWindowPosition()` to scale for the new client size.

Comment: ...and finally call `UpdateWindow(hWnd)` after all `SetWindowPosition`.

Comment: I'm unclear on the question.  What exactly is the problem?  It appears to be working.

Answer (score 1):

```
HWND hwndTextField = CreateWindow(L"Static", L"",
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP,
        0, 0, WINDOWSIZEW, WINDOWSIZEH / 6,
        hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

`hwndTextField` is declared on stack, it will be forgotten as soon as it goes out of scope, you won't be able find the control later (not easily anyway). `hwndTextField` should be declared as static or global. Better yet, assign an ID for each control using `HMENU`. This ID can be used to find the control. Also, when you click the button it sends `WM_COMMAND` message with that ID.

The style for this control should be `WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP`. However `WS_TABSTOP` is ignored unless this is created in a dialog.

And resize the controls in a separate function, so that it can be done from both `WM_CREATE` and `WM_SIZE`

For example

```
#define ID_TEXT 100
...

case WM_CREATE:
{
CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, HMENU(ID_TEXT), 0, NULL);
...
resize_window(hWnd);
}

case WM_SIZE:
{
resize_window(hWnd);
return 0;
}

void resize_window(HWND hwnd)
{
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

    //update ****
    WINDOWSIZEW = rc.right;
    WINDOWSIZEH = rc.bottom;

    ...
    SetWindowPos(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_TEXT), 0, x, y, w, h, SWP_NOZORDER);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did what you said but it's still not working. what I did wrong ? (code updated)

Comment: Show more code. Is `WINDOWSIZEW` and `WINDOWSIZEH` updated in `resize_window()` ?